# How to select date from datepicker in selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to select date from datepicker, below things i tried

1. Identify the text box in which selected date gets entered.
2. Identify the datepicker ICON and click on that so that it gets open with current 
   date highlighted.

Here if I pass required date directly to date text box through sendkeys, it works. But i want to select the date from datepicker which is very old like "10/2/1895", then how to do..?

Html Code:

```
<img src="/img/default/extjs/s.gif?hash=797058701" class="x-form-trigger x-form-date-trigger " id="ext-gen7">
```

Clicking on the image which opens dataPickerCalendar

```
Driver.pFCreateTaskUnderProject.getDpImage().click(); 
Driver.pFCreateTaskUnderProject.getTxtDateOFBirth()...????????
```

Here i am not able to proceed. How to select the date[10-2-1952] from the calendar..?
If manual then we will go back to 1952, then select 2nd month and 10th Date. But with automation how to do this...?

Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: We can't guess what to do without seeing the HTML code. Can you give us more information?

Comment: You can do this using xpath very easily. Please share the html for the calendar.

Comment: There few questions already asked in similar pattern regarding jQuery Date Picker Please Search.

Can refer http://vishalsangave.blogspot.in/2012/07/date-picker-jquery-selenium.html

Vishal

Comment: Html Code:
<img src="/img/default/extjs/s.gif?hash=797058701" class="x-form-trigger x-form-date-trigger " id="ext-gen7">

Clicking on the image which opens dataPickerCalendar
Driver.pFCreateTaskUnderProject.getDpImage().click(); 
Driver.pFCreateTaskUnderProject.getTxtDateOFBirth().sendKeys("10/02/1945");  //dd-mm-yy
Here i am not able to proceed. How to select the date from the calendar..?